# C skipping line starts with '#'

Tags: c

im trying read a file and using fscanf to get some values down and store it in an array, however in the file, there will be some line starts with '#" (e.g. #this is just a command), and i want to skip them how should i do that? those lines that contains # will appear at random lines. got some of my code here:

```
//do line counts of how many lines contain parameters 


while(!EOF) {
      fgets(lines, 90, hi->agentFile);
      count++;
      if (lines[0] == '#') {
          count--;
      }
  }
   //mallocing an array of struct.
  agentInfo* array = malloc(count*sizeof(agentInfo));
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      fscanf(hi->agentFile,"%d %d %c %s %c",&array[i].r,&array[i].c,
              &array[i].agent_name,&array[i].function[80],
              &array[i].func_par);
```

so i need to add something so i can skip lines start with '#', how?

Comment: In addition to JonathanLeffler's answer, I would use a linked list instead of an array and do all the work one single loop.

Comment: `EOF` is a macro that expands to a constant negative value, the value returned by certain input functions when they have no input to read. `!EOF` is simply zero. `while (!EOF)` is valid C, but makes no sense. Always check the value returned by any input function (`fgets`, `fscanf`, etc.), and use that value to determine when you're done. Different input functions indicate this differently; read the manual for each one.

Answer (score 3):

Your EOF test is wrong.  You also need to rewind the file between the `fgets()` loop and the `fscanf()` loop.  And you need to replace the `fscanf()` loop with a second `fgets()` loop using `sscanf()` to read the data.  Or you need to allocate the memory as you go while reading the file once.  Let's leave that for later, though:

```
while(fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), hi->agentFile) != EOF)
{
      if (lines[0] != '#')
          count++;
}
agentInfo *array = malloc(count*sizeof(agentInfo));
if (array != 0)
{
    int i;
    rewind(hi->agentFile);
    for (i = 0; fgets(lines, sizeof(lines), hi->agentFile) != EOF && i < count; i++)
    {
        if (lines[0] != '#')
        {
            if (sscanf(lines, "%d %d %c %s %c",&array[i].r,&array[i].c,
                     &array[i].agent_name,&array[i].function[80],
                     &array[i].func_par) != 5)
                ...format error in non-comment line...
        }
    }
    assert(i == count);  // else someone changed the file, or ...
}
```

Note that this checks for a memory allocation error and for format errors for non-comment lines.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does that `sscanf` do the expected thing? Always a little apprehensive when mixing `%s` and spaces.

Comment: @DennisMeng: It does more or less what I expect — and I had to take it on trust that it does what the OP wants.  The space between the two `%d` conversions is harmless (though technically unnecessary); the ones before the `%c` conversions are crucial — they skip white space; the one between `%c` and `%s` is likewise harmless. I'd be happy with the format as given for consistency. It would convert a line containing `123 456 * alphabet &` happily, for example. Whether that's what the input looks like is more open to debate, but in the absence of other information, the format string is fine.